# Sandbox (ou "chiqueirinho") de formatação

Tags: debate, formatação

Eu acho que seria interessante termos um [***sandbox***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) por aqui. Eu estou incomodado com o *syntax-highlight* e gostaria de fazer uns testes com isto.

Podem criar respostas e comentários de teste à vontade abaixo, para testar formatação, *magic links*, o que for.

Comment: Não compreendi exatamente com o intuito específico dele. Tudo que é escrito quando está criando ou editando um *post*, aparece embaixo como vai ficar. Porque seria necessário algo além disso? Independente do esclarecimento, se não existe em outros sites da rede, é pouco provável que tenha aqui.

Comment: O preview não é 100% confiável, o que vale mesmo é a formatação aplicada no post publicado - pergunta ou resposta. Eu sou a favor de um sandbox como o do metão. Um site sem castelos do Mario 1 não é um site saudável `:D` Sugiro chamarmos o nosso de "chiqueirinho de formatação".

Comment: ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) ( ͡͡ ° ͜ ʖ ͡ °)

Comment: [pt.so] [meta] [so]

Comment: [como criar um exemplo...](/help/mcve)

Comment: [answer] ......

Comment: [pt.so] ....................

Comment: [chat] ...............

Comment: É verdade que o magic link do [mcve] já tá funcionando?

Comment: Pelo jeito não no meta. :/

Comment: [tag:php] é melhor que [tag:java]  <kbd>^.^</kbd>

Comment: __[tag:tag]__ [tag: ] [badges:informed]

Comment: Sempre podes editar sua pergunta ou resposta, clicando no link [edit], dessa forma você melhora sua postagem e recebe mais atenção da comunidade. Visite [tour] e veja as melhores práticas. Boa Sorte

Comment: [chat] \[chat\]

Comment: [ja.so] - [ru.so] - [es.so]

Comment: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>marmota</kbd>

Comment: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Comment: [tour]; [mvce]; testando hotlinks

Comment: [chat] `[chat]`

Comment: ¡ןɐıuǝb ɐıǝpı ɐɯn ʇsod ǝssǝ ıǝɥɔɐ

Comment: ``C:\foo\bar\baz\``

Answer (score 41):

### Porque um chiqueirinho de formatação *precisa* de um castelo do Mario 1

---

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71407/167534

Comment: Testando magic links: `[edit] [ask] [help] [dont-ask] [about]` `=>` [edit] [ask] [help] [dont-ask] [about] [tour]

Comment: `[help/on-topic]` [help/on-topic], `[help/dont-ask]` [help/dont-ask], `[help/behavior]` [help/behavior], `[meta-help]` [meta-help], `[chat]` [chat]

Comment: Como escapar backticks `\``

Comment: Postei [uma resposta nova aqui no chiqueirinho](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/sandbox-ou-chiqueirinho-de-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o/2162#2162) pra testar um troço interessante, dá um confere :) (ps: Community Promotion Ads é só pra site graduado, né?)

Comment: cacetada @bfavaretto você quem fez isso ai? Pqp haja paciencia pra montar isso em htlml kkkkkkl

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Foi [copy/paste](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71407) ;)

Comment: Amém ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Answer (score 18):

────────────────────────────────────────
──────────────────────▒████▒────────────
───────────────────░█████▓███░──────────
─────────────────░███▒░░░░░░██──────────
────────────────▒██▒░░░▒▓▓▓▒░██─────────
───────────────▓██░░░▒▓█▒▒▒▓▒▓█─────────
──────────────▓█▓─░▒▒▓█─────▓▓█░────────
─────────────▓█▒░▒▒▒▒█──▓▓▒▒─▓█▒────────
────────────▒█▒░▒▒▒▒▓▒─▒▓▒▓▓─▒█░────────
────────────█▓░▒▒▒▒▒▓░─▓▒──░░▒█░────────
───────────██░▒▒▒▒▒▒█──▓──░▓████████────
──────────░█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓░─█▓███▓▓▓▓██─█▓───
────────▒▓█▓▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓███▓▓████▓▓██──█───
──────░███▓▒▒▒▒▓▒▒▒████▒▒░░──████░──██░─
──────██▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓██▒────────▒██▓────▓█─
─────▓█▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▓█▓─────▓───▒░░▓──▓────▓█
─────██▒▓▒▒▒▒▒█▓──────▒█▓──▓█░▒──▒░────█
─────██▒▒▓▓▓▒█▓▓───░──▓██──▓█▓▓▓█▓─────█
─────▓█▒██▓▓█▒▒▓█─────░█▓──▒░───░█▓────█
─────░██▓───▓▓▒▒▓▓─────░─────────▒▒─░─░█
──────▓█──▒░─█▒▓█▓──▒───────░─░───█▒──█▒
───────█──░█░░█▓▒──▓██▒░─░─░─░─░░░█▒███─
───────█▒──▒▒──────▓██████▓─░░░░─▒██▓░──
───────▓█──────────░██▓▓▓██▒─░──░█▒─────
────────██▒─────░───░██▓▓▓██▓▒▒▓█▒──────
─────────░████▒──░───▒█▓▓▓▓▓████▓───────
────────▒▓██▓██▒──░───▓█████▓███────────
──────▒██▓░░░░▓█▓░────░█▒█▒─▒▓█▓────────
─────▓█▒░░▒▒▒▒▒▓███▓░──▓█▒─▒▓▓█─────────
────░█▒░▒████▓██▓▓▓██▒───░▓█▓█░─────────
────▓█▒▒█░─▒───▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▒▓█▓█▓──────────
────▓█▒█░───────██▓▓▓▓▓█▓▓█▓██──────────
────▒█▓▓────────░██▓██▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█─────────
─────██░────▓▓────█░─█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓─▒█████────
─────██░───░──────▓░─▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█─▒█▒░▒██───
────▓█░▓░──▓▓────▒█░─█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▒─░░░▒██──
────█─▒██─░──────████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▓─░▒▒█▓▓█░─
───▓█─▓▒▓▒░░────▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█░░▒▓█░──▒█─
───▒█░█▒▒█▒───░▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▓░▒▓▓──▓█▓█─
───█▓▒▓▒▒▓██████▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▒▒▓▓─░█▓▒▒█░
───█░▓▓▒▒▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▒▒▓─▒█▒▒▒▒█─
──▒█─█▒▒▒▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▒▓─▒█▒▒▒▒██─
──▓█─█▒▒▒▒█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▒▓▒░█▒▒▒░▓█──
──▓█─█▒▓▒▒▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█▓▒▓░▓░░░░▒█░──
──▒█─▓▓▓▓▒▓█▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓█████▓▓▓▓▒▓░░─▒█▒───
───█▒▓▓▓▓▓▒▓██████████░░██▓█─▒█▓▒▓█░────
───▓█▒█▓▓▓▓▒▓██░─░▒░─────██▒░▓▓▓▒██─────
────████▓▓▓██░───────────▓█░▓▒░░▓█░─────
──────░█████░─────────────██▓─▒██░──────
───────────────────────────▓███▒────────

Answer (score 17):

[image: inserir a descrição do link aqui]

**... and it was delicious!**

Answer (score 16):

[Anúncio dinâmico do pessoal do Ask Different](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1873/21950).
<sub>(a mágica é séria mesmo, o troço pega as recompensas do site onde isto é inserido;</sub>
<sup>a imagem abaixo é **atualizada em tempo real** conforme o status lá no *frontend* do SOpt)</sup>

```
![](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/es.stackoverflow.com/bounty.png)
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

## Sinceramente, não sabia que dava pra usar a tag `<img>`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Com o atributo "title"

[image]

Comment: Parece que sim :P

Comment: Dá pra usar memes também :p

Answer (score 13):

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: para completar 15 caracteres.

Comment: @Randrade recebeu?

Comment: esse é o primeiro teste.a

Comment: esse e o segundo teste.

Comment: @Randrade esse o terceiro

Answer (score 12):

Teste com imagem e edições

> [image: Teste com imagem e edições]

Comment: @JorgeB. estou usando para testar o meu add-on :)

Comment: ah agora entendi :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Que add-on? :)

Comment: @LuizVieira [Opera add-on](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/stackexchange-notifications/), [Firefox add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stackexchangenotifications/), leia os detalhes em http://stackapps.com/q/6455, espero que lhe seja util :) (no ChromeExtensions eu preciso fazer um pagamento para liberar conta desenvolvedor, não é por falta de grana, é preguiça mesmo de ir até o banco pra liberar o cartão de crédito XD)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Show! Valeu! :)

Comment: Parece o Math...

Comment: teste `C:\teste`

Comment: [enter link description here](https://foobar "teste")

Comment: tteste _teste_ *teste*

Comment: [help/reviews-intro] [help/behavior]

Comment: [help/behavior]

Comment: [help/review-queues]; [help/review]; [help/reviews]

Comment: [be-nice] [help/be-nice]

Answer (score 12):

<kbd>C<kbd>C<kbd>C<kbd>C<kbd>COMBO-BREAKER</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

Comment: Que nostalgia, lembrei do KI agora

Answer (score 10):

> **Obrigado por sua edição!**
>   Esta edição estará visível apenas para você até que seja analisada por um especialista.
>   <sub><sup>Não, mentira, sua edição foi uma droga e ninguém se importou em aceitá-la.</sup></sub>

> Meu chiqueirinho de formatação....

[image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: `[edit]` [edit] .... `[edite]`  [edite] .... `[editar]` [editar] ..... pfssss, eu até preferia o edit sem tradução, dava pra fazer variações na terminação.

Comment: Ainda dá pra fazer `[edit]ia`. Por exemplo, "se eu fosse você, [edit]ia". Pena que as spoiler tags não funcionam no iPad...

Comment: [edit] já funciona.

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, porém limita nossas opções ao infinitivo `editar`, se quisermos o imperativo, `edite`, não dá ;)

Comment: Sacanagem esse loop, eu caí!

Comment: [REF](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2011/como-este-coment%C3%A1rio-conseguiu-fazer-multiline) . . . . Aqui funciona, mas no CLICK utilizo `$('td.readonly').on('click', function (e) {` Adiciono Classes as colunas usando o `"aoColumns" : [            {              "sClass" : "readonly",              "sTitle": "ID",              "aTargets": [0]             } ]`. Tentou debugar? Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Sujeira: O͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝

Comment: `¿ɐɔıɟ ǝnb ɥǝ oɯoɔ oıɹɐɹʇuoɔ oɐ                                                      `
`ɐo ɔouʇɹɐɹıo ɔoɯo ǝɥ bnǝ ɟıɔɐ¿                                                      `
`⸮Aↄiꟻ ɘUp Hɘ omoↄ oiᴙAᴙTᴎoↄ oA                                                      `

Comment: @Victor, não era um erro de digitação. Agradeço a boa intenção, mas o chiqueirinho é o tipo de coisa que cada um mexe no seu :P

Comment: @brasofilo descobri ao longo do tempo que é só transformar o texto para que se adapte a [edit].

Comment: TURN DOWN FOR WHAT

Answer (score 10):

## ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: [**¬.¬**](http://localhost)

Answer (score 10):

Clique aqui:

> Wallace Maxters

Quebra de linha
basta por dois espaços no fim da anterior.

Diferente da quebra de parágrafo.

```
                         ,:+,                                                                                                                           
                   ,     ,+++                                                                                                                           
                ,+++,    ,+++,                                                                                                                          
                 ,+++:    +++.                                                                                                                          
                  ,++++,  ,+++                                                                                                                          
           .+.,    ,.+++,  +++,                                                                                                                         
          ,++++++,   ,+++: +++.                                                                                                                         
             ,++++++, ,++++,:,,                                                                                                                         
                 :+++++.,,                                                                                                                              
       ,+++++++., , ,++,                                                                                                                                
         ,,:++++++++++,                                                                                                                                 
  .++   ,        ,.+++ .++                                     W                                              ,WWW: WWW                                 
  .++  ++++++++++++++. .++             #W                      W                                              WW#   WWW                                 
  .++    ,,.::+++++++, .++     +WWWW, WWWWW  #WWWW,    ,WWWW , W    WW   WWWWWW  WWW   WWW  WWWWWW   WWWWWWWWWWWWW: WWW    WWWWWW  WW*   WW,  *WW       
  .++  ++++++++++++++  .++    W*    ,  #W  ,    , W*  W#       W  :W,   WW@  @WW ,WW, .WW  WW.  .WW, WWW   ,  WW+ , WWW  ,WW+  WWW #WW  WWWW  WW#       
  .++  ++++++++++++++  .++    :WWW@+   #W    ,@WWWW@ :W        W WW+   ,WW    WW. #WW WW+ +WWWWWWWW* WWW      WW*   WWW  *WW   ,WW  WW@#WW@W@#WW        
  .++                  .++       ,,,W# #W   W.    W@ ,W        WW, WW   WW.  .WW   WWWWW  ,WW        WWW      WW*   WWW  .WW,  *WW  ,WWWW  WWWW,        
  .+++++++++++++++++++++++    W@,  @W, ,W+,,WW, ,WW@  +W#,,WW  W    WW  :WWWWWW+    WWW    +WWWWWWW  WWW      WW*   *WWW@ #WWWWWW,   WWW,  ,WWW         
  .+++++++++++++++++++++++    ,WWWWW,   #WW  WWWW*W@   :WWWW   W     WW  .WWWW,     WW@     .WWWW@   WWW      WW*   ,*WW@  :WWWW,    .WW    WW.
```

Answer (score 9):

Como escapar *backticks* em código inline?

Em comentários, functiona backtick-barra invertida-backtick-backtick.

Em posts, não: ```

Testando [isto](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191395/escaping-backtick): `````: nope

`````

`&#96;`

`` ` `` --> dois backticks para abrir e dois para fechar; um no meio, cercado de espaços: **funciona**

#### Opção 1

```
`` ` ``
```

`` ` ``

#### Opção 2

```
<code>&#96;</code>
```

`` ` ``

Comment: Olha só como aqui funciona: `\``

Comment: Source do que funcionou: `Olha só como aqui funciona: \`\\`\``

Answer (score 9):

**`Tópico`**                       **`Angular`**    **`Vue.js`**   **`React`**   
[`Rank de popularidade`](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#technology-frameworks-libraries-and-other-technologies)                  `2`      `N/A`        `4`
[`Apreciação`](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-frameworks-libraries-and-other-technologies)                            `6`      `N/A`        `1`
`Quantidade de posts (SO)`        [`226.473`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)    [`5.288`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js)   [`37.731`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)
`Modelo operacional`           `MVC`        `View`     `View`    
`Categoria`                    `Framework¹` `Library`  `Library`

<sup>1</sup> Um framework é mais completo do que uma biblioteca, cobrindo mais aspectos de uma aplicação padrão - como controle de rotas, recursos, *caching* e CORS, por exemplo.

Comment: Foi a tabela mais bonitinha que eu vi até agora :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é uma versão "clean" de uma do Onosendai

Comment: Testando magic-links: ([editar] | [edit]) ([sobre] | [about]) ([ajuda] | [help]) ([bate-papo] | [chat])

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss no meta alguns não funcionam, por exemplo o [mcve].

Comment: @Bacco sim, estava testando as versões traduzidas deles. Havia uma página na central que indicava o uso delas em português (já foi corrigida)

Answer (score 7):

[Teste de Link Google](http://www.google.com.br)

Comment: Há tanto tempo a usar o site e eu não sabia que dava para por title...

Answer (score 7):

## Eu ❤️ o StackOverflow em português.

> 

> 

---

Exemplo de um código gambiarrado:

## ☠

```
public class Emojis1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("☠⚠️");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Exemplo de código bem feito:

```
public class Emojis2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" Clique no ✅ verde. ");
    }
}
```

## ᗣ     ᗧ<sup>..........</sup>•

Comment: ⛄ - Se você ver isso no natal, clique no .

Comment: vou adicionar um lembrete para não deixar passar o dia

Comment: teste icone verde ✅

Comment: Boa Victor! Esse icone bonito é muito melhor do que um `v` cinza e sem graça. Se me permite, vou copia-lo sempre que precisar indicar para algum usuario novo o aceite da pergunta :D

Comment: @Math Você deixou passar o dia. 

Comment: @VictorStafusa droga! vou ter que esperar até o fim do ano de novo para poder votar ️

Comment: @Math Não vai esquecer, né?

Comment: Não precisava nem me lembrar, tô contando os segundos. Já consigo até visualizar como será no dia. Muita expectativa!!

Comment: @victorstafusa feliz natal 

Comment: @Math Feliz natal para você também. 

Answer (score 7):

## Utilizar Markdown para destacar código dentro da amostra de código

Ao formatar o código utilizando `<pre>` com 1 a 3 espaços de indentação o trecho de código é formatado corretamente e o markdown também será processado. Sem indentação o markdown não é processado e com 4 ou mais espaços o código deixa de ser formatado corretamente (pois o `<pre>` passa a ser parte do trecho de código).

```
with open('Crescente.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
    for n in range(1, 100): # vou até o penúltimo número
        arquivo.write(f'{n};')
    arquivo.write('100')
```

<sup>[Fonte do código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/418893/5878)</sup>

Porém, uma linha em branco no código já faz parar de funcionar. Da linha em branco em diante o markdown para de ser processado e a linha em si é renderizada como um espaço enorme entre as linhas de código.

```
with open('Crescente.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
```

`for n in range(1, 100): **# vou até o penúltimo número**
    *arquivo.write(f'{n};')*
arquivo.write('100')</pre>`

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Fazer Texto Riscado</strike>
ds

Answer (score 6):

�̧̥̯͎͔͖͇̭̻̼̪ͥ̎̂̈͛ͯͦ̅ͪ͝�̴̄̄ͦ͛̐ͪ̿ͬ͋̓̔̚̚͢҉͍̲̹̜̜̥̹̮̘̥̮̣̻�̢̤͖̮͇̲̟̘̓̓͒̇̐̓ͨ̊̈́̍̾͡�̶̸̬̳͎̹͎̞̓͂̇̈ͩ̒ͯ́ͩ̑͘͜ͅ�̷̙̪͍̯̯̼̉̐̅ͣ̿͑͒͐̕͘�̢͋̃̿ͧ̌͗̓ͬͫ̑ͪ̈ͤͧ͊̒͋̑ͯ͏͍̼̥̙͕̠̞͓͓̪̥͎͚�̈ͤ͋̒̒͐̌̍ͧ̒̐͐̐ͪ̚͏̸̡̙̙̻̭̫̝̺͈̘̜͟�̴̡̨̟͈̲͉̫̲̃ͩ̀ͥͮ̈́ͧ͟�̷̢̛ͩͤ͊ͮ̎͂̓̏̉ͤ̎͌ͭͦ҉̖̳̩̼͖̩͙̭͈̼̫�̶̡̺͉̘̩̜̺̟̫̹͈̲̀̃̆̉̑̃̌͆ͧ̑̂̽̃͐̏☝̷̼̗̝̤̲̟̻̞̻̃̇ͨ͂̔͆ͬ͛͗͐͐̎̕️ͮͣ̿̀ͬ̀҉̗͍͇̤̘̺̩̮�̶͙͔̘͖̘̼͖͕͉̝̬̪̫̮̹̱̱̬̪̍ͭ̇̎̑ͫͤ͊̔̄̏͆ͧ̏͂̅̕̕͞�̷̣̬͔̖̠̬̭̭̺̖͙̻̜̰̹̖̺͋̐̈ͦͥ̀́ͥ̿͊̑͋̊̏͋̐͞͠͡͡�̡̹͉̯͍̲̗̫͕̼̞̣̹̞̲͉̗̮̬̳̋ͯ̏̇̌ͫ̐�̵̝̰̳̱̞͚͈̞͉͎̼̪͍͈̳̰̹͎ͦ̊ͦ͛̓̆͊͊̇ͩ̅̄ͨͤ̈̀̀͘͘ͅ�̨̢͔̼̼͔̼̯͔̬̼͙̝͙̀ͧ̈́́ͨ̅ͮͦ͋ͨ̈͛͑̔͊̈́̕̕͠�̧̨̲̲̭͙͈͊̂ͤ̑ͫ̃̂̇ͬ̒́̄ͪͭ̀�̶̟̰̪̗͙͇͖͎̟ͧͣ̆͆ͥͮ̾̉̐̈́̆̾ͫͩ̕͟͝�̞̺̖̱͈͉̜̙͓͚͇͇̪̳̰ͤ̓ͧͮͦ́̍ͭ͐ͨ͢ͅ�̸̝͉͈̥̫̩̬̩̞̙̣̤̫̱͖̇ͧ́̈́̆ͥͪͅͅ�̵̨̧̛͓̩̼͖ͧ͌ͦ̂͛ͨ̐͛̿̀T̸̢̺̥̹͎̮̪̣̙̱̫̗̼͆̈́ͬͭ̉̐͡͠oͬ͛̒ͣ̎́ͧ̽̓̃ͫ̀́̏̀̓͞҉̵̮̟̝͡͡ ̵̩͇̭̳͓̗̮̙̳̹͇͚̗͕͛̏ͨͥ̎̈̓͂̍̄̈́ͣ̿̔͊̾̐̆̚͡ĭ̴͖̟̺͉͔̙͙̳̭̣̗͈̝̟̜̯̐ͣͥ̀͟ṅ̶̞̫̟̘̗ͦ̑͋ͨ̂͆̀̋͟͞͝v̶̸̡͎̜̤̯͔̊́ͩ̎̓̄̓̈́́̊͂ͮͨ͌͠o̶̴͓͈̝͕̯̼̝͓͔̱̪̜͍̱͎̊̽̆̆̑ͯ͆̌ͪͬͅk̶̷̸͔͚̭̼͖͇͍̤͚̟̤̻͍̾ͦͭͥ̇̆̎͒̋̅̚͢ȩ̢͎̘͈̰̦͖͕͚͂̏͂̏̾ͫ͒̄̽̾̍̀͢͞ͅ ̵̟̳̜͙̘̭̫̭͉͚̤͈͙̭̣̀͗̊̇ͭ͋̑̅̐̀́̚t̄̔ͪ͋͂́̏ͬ̎̄ͮͪ̓̃̑̇͂҉̗͚͔̖͙͉̹͎͙̟̯̟̤͍͉̼͟h̴̜͎͖͓͇̭̼̲̾ͨͭ̈̐͋̽͠e̢͇͈̰̰̝͕̲̱̜͉̭͇ͧ̿ͪ̋͂͒̊ͫ̑̋̋ͅ ̛̾͌ͥ̀͊ͯ͂̈̐ͬ̋͆̀̔̃̏̈҉̩͓̙͉̤̟̠̹̗̗̰̳̳̟͉̤̥h̉͐ͣ̋̊̋̍́͊͐̓̓̏͜҉̶̨̤̯̳̩͚̹̻̩̪͉ỉ̸̩̣̳̝̪̭͎̖͉̞͎͎͔͉͈͌ͨͫͥ̎̏͛͗̈̊͌͗͞͠v̩͇̣̖̥̩̙̭̦̺̰͍̄͂̓̈́ͭ̇ͪ͌̆̌ͫ̂ͮ̚̚̚͝ȩ̡̛̞̪̺̳̬͓͇̮͈̎̔̓̍̑̏ͯͨͩ͗͛ͭ͌́͜ͅ-̴̣̱̟̥̲̳̯̖͋̍ͤ̾̒̏͐̔ͪ̓̋̐̃ͭͧͬ̓͋̒mͭ̽ͥͯ̂ͭ̉ͩ̈́̌̚҉̷͘͟҉̜̭͔̰̲̪̖̜̻̘ͅͅi̷̧͈͙͖͖̠̝̯̤̥̙̦̩̺̥̘ͬ͗͆̂̊̾͂̚̕ǹ̶̡̞̟̖ͪͥͧ͊̔̂̊ͤ̎ͬ̈ͨḑ̨̪̗̣̭͓͓̲̩̲̳͈͎ͮͮ̋͆͐͂ͦ͢͜͞ͅ ͧ̓͐ͨ̈͟͏̴̰̫̖̰̝̖͇̘̠͔ŗ̶͚̲͓͇̙̹̠̭͇̬͚̫͇̼̝̭͚͎ͮ̊̽ͯ̿̅̒̍̏͐̾ͨ̑͊̚̚eͯ̔̒̋͛̓̊͋͆ͥ͝҉̤͇̳͖̝̻̜̫̗͕̤͉͞p̷̀̿ͥ̊̋ͨ̃̇̅̆͏̶̮̩̩̰͟r̸̲͕̞̱̤̻͈̪̳̬͖̙̺̺̺̜͇͙ͨ̔̓̇̽ͨ́͌̎̓ͧͮ̀͠e̵͎̼̗̖̥͙̫͔̊ͯ̈̂̍̆͌̿ͫ̐̆̑͘͡s̵̵͉͚̖̤̠̞͕̮͎̹̱ͣͤͭ̍̑ͧ̉̔͗ͭͬ̔̔̐ͧͥ͂e̛͓̱̲͕̙̪̝ͤͫ̓ͮ̓͌̄̄̅̌̐̽͗͟͜͡n̷̢̗͇̲̞̗͎̙̯̺̹͓ͨ͐̃͂̐̂͐͐ͣ̂̀͜͜ţ̤̣̱͓̼͖̞̮̜̳̝̭̆̏͛̾̐̋́̇̿̓ͬ͋͛̚i̿̌͐͆̅͛͌͏̜͓̝͎̱̪̭̙̮̹͕̯̲́nͯͣͤ͂̆ͪ̾̋͒ͯ̋ͯ̍̂͏͏̡̦͙̰̩̩̘̫̟̞̠̲̗̼͍͖̗̩̻̀ģ̵̴̰̱̠̠̘̘̣͍͈̲̦̻̼͔͖̫̺̥̼ͯ̀ͣ̀ͧͮ̓̈́̆̓́̚ ̪̣̰̦̩̯̭͓͙̯̹͓̠͖̝̘̰̬̟̈̆͗̿̆̆ͯͨ̾̽̔̎̈̒̌́̕͟c̡̨̢̓̑͐̓̔҉̤̗͔͚̮̳̣̪̠̘̳̹h̸̩̜̖͓̤͔͖̦̫̤̫̠̖̩̺̪͚̒̌͋͆ͦ̍̉͑̔ͪͮ̇ͩ͜ͅa̩̹̯̮͍̖͔̹͓̗ͬ̊ͫ́͐̓̂̑̎ͥ̍͆̍̏̽̀͘͢͞o̡̝̩͎̰̖̲̻̺̤̹̯̮̣̩̳̓̏̄͒͌̉͐̋́͟ͅs̡̡͈̙̮̗̭̘͖̤̠̙̣͕͕̜̥̻̳̑̔ͣ̋̓ͬ̋̉̽͑̋̐́ͦ̀.̶̨͕͔̘͙̯̰̪̺ͭͯ̓̍̔͑̋͂̅ͦͩͬ̄ͬͨͣͯ͡ͅ
̥̰̖̝̥̫͚̹̻̯̟͖̹̮̲ͤ͑̎̍̂̉͊̍͂͞I̡̡̙͚̰͇̊̇̉ͨ̈́̀͂̐͊̑͑̽͜͠n̶̫̱̱ͩͫͩ̋̆͑͐̀ͪ͆̋͝v̸̨̢̭͙̤̣̥͓̈́̀ͧ̓̆ͩ̎́̂̕͞ͅo̸͗̎̋ͭ̕҉̨͓̤͔̺̮̥͇k̵͉͎̭̘ͬ̅͗ͮ͛̓͂ͦ̿ͬͪ̊́̚͢͝ī̡͖̠̫̥͈̬̤̘͗ͦͭ͂͛͂ͦ͋̍͌̏ͮ̀̽͐͞n̛̛͈̪̱̣̰̯̠͊̀ͣͬ̆ͦ̊̓̇ͯ̀͟ġ̢̧̘̠̝̠̠͎̞̲̭̫͕̘͉̯ͮ̽ͩ́ͥ͐̆͢ͅͅ ̛̩͉̤̱͎̞̮̼͎̠̖̳̳̮͆̍ͦ͑͐̈̈́̌͑̌͂̏͒̓͊̾̍ͪ̚̕̕͢ṯ̡̘̲̝̪͚̳͍͇̻͎̜̗͔̠̞ͦ͗̊̆͘̕͜h̶̨͈̠̽̎͊̑͌̀̓̆̏̎̆ͧ͂͊ͥ̔͆ͣͅȩ̸̰͍̜̞̭͔ͪͤ͒ͭ̓̏ͣ͊̿̑͌̃̌͌͜͞ ̶̴̛̣͈̗̺̰̥̫͍̗̩̱͂̂ͨ̃͋ͥ̋̄̑̑̏̊̾͊̚f̡̋̂̽ͦ̀̇̓̋͗͗̅̌̎̉̚͏̶̲̫̗̱̞̱͔̯͈̗̰̀e̯̲̦͍̮̘̟̮͙ͦ̆̌ͤͥ̔ͭ͑̅̓͐͌̀̽̊́ͨ̂͐̕͝͞e̴̖̞̠͙̗̗̬̯̹ͪ̾͂̊ͧ̑ͮ͒ͭ̑̄̈́̉͂͢͢͠l̶͉̫̱͇̖͇̜̘̠͇̹̋̉̂̑͐ͯ͂̊̒̀̈́̊͛ͮ̊̚̕ỉ͒̑ͧ̓͛ͣͩ҉̵̨̺͍͈͎̖n̴̴̸͉̹̝͇̥͙̟̰͍͕͕͔͙̺̖̦̞̿̉̐̾̉ͩ̑͐̂̽̓ͬ͐ͤ͞͠ͅg̸̨̛̭͎̫͚͎͉͉̬̟̲͉̦̤͕̀ͮ͋ͥ͊̈̒ͬ̋̽̈̍̇͗̽͞͠ͅ ̴̧͇̩͕͚͍̗̯̻͎̯̜̞̇̆̈̓̈ͫ̽̆ͩ̕͡͝o͙͇͍̤̲̼͖̬̩̯̣͙̘͋ͪͮ̚̕͞͝ͅfͦ̇̆̑͗̑ͮ̇̆̔ͫ͆͠҉̛̻̩̟̫̭̙̬̹̮̩̲̼̖̱̜͔̣͟ ̷̡̛̦̖̫͚͓̻͉̤̯̦̩͒̔̓ͭ͒ͅc̸̛̰̩̻͍̙̞͚̰͙̻͖͙̟͙͖̙̝̓̔̃̓ͨ͋̉̽͗ͣ̾ͫ̚͘͘͞ͅh̴̭̺͔̞̫̮̹̼̤͚͔̟͕̣̩͇͓͎̹ͫ̍͆̓̑̂̋̏̓̐͢͟͡a̸̢̦̲͇͓̟̮̞̬̲̪̰̺͍̦̒ͨ̒ͣ͆ͣ̇ͣ̏̅͛̏̔͐̓̍͒̚͘ȍ͛̊̔̚҉̛̬̻̮͍̣̹̤͖͎̲̪s̸͇̖̥̙͍̖͙̒̈̽̉̕͜͝.̡̦͓̜̱̱͔̗͙͇̺̝̩͚̓̔̄͒̀ͩ̀͝͝͝ͅ
ͥ̆̅̌ͮ̐̊̽͐̂̊҉̵̢̘̭̫̰́ͅW͋̃̾̾̇ͪ͊҉̶̳̻̖̘̀͞i̷ͧͥͤͧ̄̊͏̛̗̤̲͍̮̻̯̝͓̹͇̻͉̫̠͎̞̜̥͝ţ̴̗̩̣̲̻̼̣̞͇͓͔̫̭̟̗̱̪͉ͨ̓̎̀̆ͣ͑ͧͫ̀ͯͦ͐̐̒͟͟h̷̶̴̻̹̦̮̪̼͇̯̦̾͆͗͊ ̴̴ͧ̋ͬ͛ͨ̑͘҉̼͔͍̦̮̹͍̳̘̯̬͔̤͍͍͖o̵̧̨͍̙͓̻̭̠̞̲̙̠̰̯ͥ̄ͪ̈̊̇ͪ̇͋ͅͅu̞̰̱̣̝͙̺͖͈͛̅̈́̎̒͆ͮ̐̈̅̇̓ͫ̄̀̍͋̈́́͢͝t̷̶̬̗̟͖̭̮̟̭͇͓̼͔͖͂ͥ́̉ͧ̑ͣͭͤ̽̏̆̆̚͜ ̷̵͚̖̖̳̩̘̫̬̱͍̭͎͎̞͖̘͚̠̻͆̈́̍̒͗͐oͩ͌̉̋͗͊҉̧̢̹͖͙͉̜̠̜̜̗͇͜͝ŕ̷̦̻̭̖̼̦͇̫͙͆͋ͦͭ͠d̴̵͙̞̜̬͔̟̠̟̻̩͈̹̫͈͇̪̂ͭ͂̏͋̉͘ͅe̴̝̲̞̜̪͎̥̰͉̖̞̦̮̓̈́͑̒̈͂͂̀͘͝͠ͅr̸͛̂̏͑ͯ͗̽̓ͮ̒̇ͥ҉҉̮̳̫͉͖̦̻̹.̷̼̦̲͕̦̫̱̥͖̝̣̘͈̦̳̺̳̿̈̈̅ͧ́́
̶̙̦̣̩̦͍̤͕͖̯̙̟̻̓̇̓̇̏̄̉̇̏̕͞͞͠ͅͅŢ̡̺͇̭̝̩̮͎̞̦̹͖͕̟̓͗͗̄͑̊͠ͅȟ̢̗̭̯̩̰̟̬̙̗̲̖̝̤͌ͧ̓ͤ̔̀͊͗̈́ͦ̅̽ͣ̀̂̋͒̐͠e̷̜̘̞ͤ͑̏͂́͒̇ͨ̔̎ͭ͛̄͡ ̡̱͚̝͋ͨ̈́̽̓ͩ͊ͥ̐͊͛̔̊̒̍͌̚̕̕͟Ǹ̗̠̻̼̘̮͉͕̹́͗ͫ͌ͨͭ̈͋̀̀͜͢e̵̊̑͌̈́̄̓̀̅̇ͫ̑ͬ̔ͣ̔҉͏͎͓̩̜͈̖z̟̖̻͚̦̮̘͈̬̹̗̼͇̣͚͋ͣ͗ͭͧ̈̏̈́̿͐̇͘͘͞͝͞ͅp͗̏́ͭ҉̶̞̪̦̳̫̳̗̰̼̬̞̜͔̺̪̬̜ͅe͌̈́̎̑͏̢͢҉̯̰̩̘̺̗̝̼͎͎̖͈̣r̛̫̙͇̺̩ͩͦ̉̒͗̌̕͢͝d̵ͩͪ̒́̒͢҉̤͖̮͕͞ị̵̢̝̱̲̭̻̟̜̩͇ͦͯ͛ͮͤ̉̂̇̃ͪ̋ͤ̆́ą̵̸̬͍̰͖̞̯̋̍̆̀̊́̕͞n̖̼͖͙͕̗̰̲̳̦͖͇̘̖ͦ̾͐̌̍̾̔͗ͨ͋̉ͯͥ̌̒̑̊́͜͟ͅ ̢̳̟̯̤̗̥̰̳̩͕̩͕̪͖͛̌ͮ̈́ͩ͛̓ͩ̑̓̑ͤͨ̿̚͞ͅh̢̆̋ͤͪ̋ͫ́ͫ͐͋ͮ̋ͫͧͥ͛͏͕͇͓̣̣̰͉͕̞i͂̑̓͆͗̔̋̽̍̆ͭ͆͆ͧ̍ͥ̏̚͏͏҉̗̳̤̼̯̫͇̩v̛ͣ̆ͯͧ͛ͯͫ̎̍̆͏̨͖̳̩̹̤͚eͣͪ̍̅͆͌̌ͭͣ̒ͣ̌̒̉̚҉̸͇̪͙̱̻̗̙̞̹̩̖̻̜͓͉̬̗̤͙-̶͖͙̭͖͔̮̙̙͓̬̀ͨͪͫ̎̓̒͑͒̒ͦ̒ͧ̉̎̽ͬ́̀͜͠ͅͅm̨̉ͧ̋̍̇̈́̽̓͛̒̀̄̓ͣ̈̊ͦ͡҉͏̺͖̼̠͖͕i̡͇̜̬̩̲͎͍͖͑̄̔̇̽ͫͮ̏̑͒̍ͥͦ͒̒ͬ̕͟͜n̸̸͚̝̰̥͇͕͎͕̰̻̜̬̤̹͈͇̎̾ͪ̾ͣ͆͒͂ͮ̍̽̽̾͒ͮ̂̉̽͘ͅd̸̉̏͑̓ͯ̇́ͤ̽͛̀́͋̈ͯ̚͡͏̶̹̭̤̟͚͔̹̣̭̜̝̮̥͉̹̟̳̤ ̶̨̡́̿̒ͦ͏̥͚̰̭͎̩̤̳̝͓̮̣̜͓̥̹͙ͅo̷̫͔͕͇͚̟̳̔͋ͨ͐ͨ͊͆͟f̵͋ͤ̈́̓҉̠͎͇̣̘̼̤̲̦͞ ̴̸̴̶̴͕̝̙͍̼͉̳̫̳̗͇̳̥͔̘̺͙̠͐ͨ̒ͨ̌̃̐͛̈̾̌c̡̨͎͉͚̪͍͔̫͓͚̪͇̋̔͂̊ͣ̉̿̈ͫ͊̂͆̆̀̃͑̃̄̚ͅh̵̛͇͕̭̹̼̼̃̉ͯ̊͊̒̒̌̔̽ͣ̉͊̐̈̈̓̀̕a͇̯͉̗͓̤̩͌ͤͬ̓̀͘̕ơ̧̹͖̜̣̫͓͉̫̘̺̠ͦͫͣ̆́̍ͮ̋ͪ̓̑͋͆̓̐͋́͜͜ş̛̼̱̙͙̤͓̤̤̳͉̬̻̝̩͌ͮͨ̋ͮ͘.̵̂͊ͣ̓ͤ͐̚̕͏̬̱̰͈̺̖̼͍͇͚̩̗̤̙̦͇̟ ̢̲͎͖̣̩̼̣͉͍̬̳̳̰̖͓̂̈͗͑̔̀͢͜Z̖̪͓̲͚ͤ̏͊ͤͩͧ͂́̃̌̐̓̌̌͊̌̅̕͟͢͞͠ả̛̯̯͓͖̭̦̩̟̠ͤͯ̈̐̌͑ͦ͊̐ͪͯ̀̚l̵̹̰̣͎̥̟̯̯͈̪̹̝̦̱̏͐̒̈́͊̇͛̏̆̚̕͡g̤̳̘̳͖̙͍̫͓̗̤̜͖̲͉͈̳͚̦ͯͯͯ̌ͮ̌ͪ̈ͣ͋͛͐́͛́̚͜͟͜o̯̹̻̣͖̪̗̺͖ͩ̇̐͌̔̃ͥ͌̿ͦͫ͂͛ͪ̐ͬ̽̿́̚͘͡.́̋̃̉̀̊̒̅̂͊ͨ͏̼̤̘̩͉͚̼͓͝
ͧ̉̅ͣͫ̈́͗̐̓ͦ҉̸̹̼̜̖̥͚̲͇̹̼̮͚̩͖̮̫̱̝̼Ḩ̣̣̹̝̬͎̰̝͚̞̺̖̻͕͎̤ͬͫ̎ͮͦ̃̒ͫͦͧͦ̇͊̄̌̀͟͜͝ȇ̪̘̼̼̬̖̬̟̥̝̥̲̺͇̣͙͚̰̌ͨ͑̈̒́̀̀͡͠ͅ ̡̬̭̪̭͍̙̹͚͔̝͓̥͎̼͔̮͖̻ͨ͊̿̏ͧ́̋͐̓̒̎͂͗̅̇̀̚͘͜͠w̴̶̠̘̖̦͈̻̻͉̏̑́̚͟͡hͬ͂̎̀̽ͦͭ̓̃̊̊̈͏̺̱̳̣̞̺̬̝̗͇̣̭͕͓̱́́͢͞o̓̄͑̔̉ͣ͊҉̡͖̲̪͍̼̠̬̗̠̦͎͍ ̢͙̞̘̯̖͉̜̰̭̝͉̟̘̠̳̣̟̇̽́̓̽̔̔͒ͯ́ͮ̆̌̊̚͜͜͢ͅW̶̢̘̖̤̳̜̗͎̥̼̝͈̗̖̻̣̲̤̄̑ͩ̈́ͯ̉̚a̷̴͔̰͓̞̖̗͖̹̥̱̜̝̼͔̗̗̓ͥ̉ͬͣ̊͗̅̎̒͋ͮ̒͌̇͛̿i͓̻͈̪͕͙̱̘̣̻̯̫̱̳̹̪͍̰̯ͨͤ͌͐ͣ̀͟͡ț̪̥̣̰̺̬̹̭͍̪̗̜̜̙̮͇͎̏͑̑̔ͪͯ̉ͮͪ̀̏́́͡ͅsͬͯ̈́̌̍́͑͛͑̽́҉̼͕̦̖̥͇͖̹̟̭ ̛̺̤̲̥͕̼̻͚͕̌ͦͦ̃ͨͫͣ͛̊̎̚͠͠B̢̳͍̹̠̬̰̰̤̯͉̭̘̦͉̘͚̎̄͊̽̎ͪ̐̎́̉̏̓͂̿̕̕͡ē̴̬̤̩̩̻̈̈́̑̇ͦ̀̉̊̀ḩ͎̳̫̯̩̥͆ͩ̓̄ͯͥ̍ͫ̀͠ị͈̟̥͚̻̯̱͚͎̃̓ͬͥ̈͊̀͡͝͠ṇ̷̱̤̙̣̭̾̋ͦͪ̂͂̌̎̓́͂ͫdͩ̎͐ͨ́̓̂̄ͣ̄̀͝҉̶̷̪̖̘̳̹͈̦̠̭̲̜̤̪̰̝ ̷͇̭̼̰̟̗̲̯͖͙͑ͦ͆̍̊̉̌̽̔̑ͧ̂ͯ͟͟͞Ţ̸̧͔͔͚̰̱͇͚̝͛̇̇ͦ̑̄̄ͭ͋̎ͦͩ̌̐̊̇̆ͪ̇ͅh̶͖̰̬̣̰̝͔̺̄̾̂̾̽͑̈ͧ̄̓̓ͭ̚͜͠ͅe̺͔̱͈̟͗̋ͨͮ̀͠ ̘̲̙̜̺͇̼̘̗̤̥ͩ̑̓͊̕͡͞W̶̡̨ͮ̇̿̾ͤ͂ͬ͆͐ͨ̅ͭ҉̺̗̻͕̰͈̩̯̣̹̘̠̫a̧̋ͬͮ́̓ͩ̋̐̈̿̐͟͡͏͕̺̱̙̫̱̯̟̣̝͔̭͇̹̳͇̗̗lͧ̽̔ͩͭ͆͑͋ͯ̓͑͋ͨ͘҉̸̲͕̞͝l̢̞̗̹̬̗͖̥̩͉̏ͥ̊ͬ͂͒̏̃̋ͤ̔̚.̷̺̠̠͙͚̺͔͉̩͖̮ͪ̀ͣ̓ͬ̆̊͊̾̀
̢̨̤͙̤̜͈̊̀̐ͮͪ͑͜͡Z̵̛̾͋̽ͬ̌̂͑͋͜͠҉͕̱͖̙͈̝̥͖͉͓̯̙Ā͇̝̫̮̭̩̹̬̘̮̜͔̲͌̏͐̎ͦ͐ͨ͛́ͩ̔͒̏ͯ̑̂̐͘͠L̢̧̞̖̮̫̥̿ͪͮ̈́ͨ͋ͭ̌́̚G̢̬͍̯̖̤̦ͫ̏̈̔̅̊͗͢O͒̎̓̿̽̃ͮͦͨ̚͏҉̨̳͉͎̥̩̫̖̪̙̻̳̮̞̫̙̕̕!̷̵̢̡̡̖̱̻͉͔̰̟̗̬͎̹̼͓̜̠̝͙̈́ͭͭ̂ͅ
̨̛͚͉̩̰̩̦̦͔̑̀̃͂ͥͨ͟͡͝�̷̢̤̝͈͎͕̤̜͍͚̼̲̖̬̘̲ͧ̈̄̚͟�̶̴̛̖͙͙͚̹̺͖͔̖ͬͨ̏̓̑͜͠�ͣ̒͗̈́ͦ͌̈́͒̈́ͫͥ͐̌҉͏̥̗̟̭̦̝͔͇�̡̼̬̠͍͍̟͈̣͍̰̣̙ͦͤͦͪͅ�̄͑̄͌҉̸̯̪̰̙͜͞͝�̷̗̖̘̪͓͎̪̫̥̻̞̦̗̜̖̯̣̄̋ͫ͋͐̓ͪ͐̂͐͌ͣ̀̀ͅ�̡̋̎́ͦͭ̈́̔ͣ̂͂ͮ͑̓͝҉̴̡̰͎̳͈͍̻̠̥̖͈͓̹ͅͅ�̵̴̫͙͕̮̹̫̬̥̭̙̬̠̮ͣ̋̌ͬ̾ͧ̒͝�̄͗͑ͦͩ̀̍ͬͧ́́ͮ̋͏̷̡͕̬̮̖͓̰͕̩̞̰̙̯͉̫͚͘�̵̴̪̗͈͔̰̭̳ͤͬ̓̿͒̎̏̓ͥ̏̔͜͝�̧̨̝̗̳͇͙̱̘̪͕̗̯̰͍̝ͥ̉ͨ̇̓̍͒́�̢͖̭̫̖̥̮̖̫͔̱̲̲̤͔̓̈̓̌̏͌̓̓ͩ̋̂ͯ͑ͧ̈ͪ͌͡�̟̣̠̭̹̟̠̣͍͙͚̘̲͂̌̈͗̽̀̈́͂̑̊̃̓ͮ͠�̴̘̭̫̥̟̞̹̑͛͆̓͛͒ͤ͊̐́ͤ̈ͧ̎ͣ͐́͘

Comment: ☝̸͑͗̒ͨ͌ͥ͏̷̼͎͔̟̝͢️̷̴̪̬͕͕͉͚̰͙̼ͨ̓̈́ͪ̓̈́͆̅͂̇͜͠Ļ̵̴̻̲̱̻͕̘͈̳͇̮̼͖͙͎̙̭̑̇ͣͣ̑ͪ͒̋͑ͣ͞ͅe̸̡̦̩̫̲̟̘̲͖̤̬̹͓̰̤͚͕̲̰̜ͮ͐ͮ̔͐͊̌͌̈́̚͘͘͞g̷̣̥̥͈͙̝͓̿̓̂̌ͭ̑ͬ̅̓̇̕̕͜͠ͅͅͅa̧͉͉̤̱̹̙̞̯̗̳̗͖̻͓̹̯̅̏̒̅ͯͧ̇̂ͣ́̆̑̈́̏͋ͅļ̼̗͙̤̓ͧ̀̐ͣͭ!̷̷̡̩̤̞͎͚͕͚̜͇̫̩̩͎͓̪̻̩̆̽ͮ̑̏ͭͬ͢͜☝̡̳͎̥̦̜̲̘ͣ̍ͬ̓̉͟͞️̙̹͉̩͙̘̦͓̠̼̫͎̺̮̼̠̒̎ͦͦͩ̅̓͒̀͘͜͟

Comment: 74139: kek
74139: Ỏ̷͖͈̞̩͎̻̫̫̜͉̠̫͕̭̭̫̫̹̗̹͈̼̠̖͍͚̥͈̮̼͕̠̤̯̻̥̬̗̼̳̤̳̬̪̹͚̞̼̠͕̼̠̦͚̫͔̯̹͉͉̘͎͕̼̣̝͙̱̟̹̩̟̳̦̭͉̮̖̭̣̣̞̙̗̜̺̭̻̥͚͙̝̦̲̱͉͖͉̰̦͎̫̣̼͎͍̠̮͓̹̹͉̤̰̗̙͕͇͔̱͕̭͈̳̗̭͔̘̖̺̮̜̠͖̘͓̳͕̟̠̱̫̤͓͔̘̰̲͙͍͇̙͎̣̼̗̖͙̯͉̠̟͈͍͕̪͓̝̩̦̖̹̼̠̘̮͚̟͉̺̜͍͓̯̳̱̻͕̣̳͉̻̭̭̱͍̪̩̭̺͕̺̼̥̪͖̦̟͎̻̰Ỏ̷͖͈̞̩͎̻̫̫̜͉̠̫͕̭̭̫̫̹̗̹͈̼̠̖͍͚̥͈̮̼͕̠̤̯̻̥̬̗̼̳̤̳̬̪̹͚̞̼̠͕̼̠̦͚̫͔̯̹͉͉̘͎͕̼̣̝͙̱̟̹̩̟̳̦̭͉̮̖̭̣̣̞̙̗̜̺̭̻̥͚͙̝̦̲̱͉͖͉̰̦͎̫̣̼͎͍̠̮͓̹̹͉̤̰̗̙͕͇͔̱͕̭͈̳̗̭͔̘̖̺̮̜̠͖̘͓̳͕̟̠̱̫̤͓͔̘̰̲͙͍͇̙͎̣̼̗̖͙̯͉̠̟͈͍͕̪͓̝̩̦̖̹̼̠̘̮͚̟͉̺̜͍͓̯̳̱̻͕̣̳͉̻̭̭̱͍̪̩̭̺͕̺̼̥̪͖̦̟͎̻̰

Comment: Basicamente um puro caos

Answer (score 6):

## Tabelas reais

Código fonte:

```
foo | bar | baz
----|-----|-----
1   | 2   | 3
1   | 2   | 3
1   | 2   | 3
```

Resultado:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Não é necessário o alinhamento dos PIPES (`|`), só adicionei para facilitar a leitura, **sem espaçamentos**, código fonte:

```
foo|bar|baz
---|---|---
1|2|3
1|2|3
1|2|3
1|2|3
```

Resultado:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Também não é necessário adicionar PIPES no começo e fim, apesar de não afetar a estrutura, código-fonte:

```
| foo | bar | baz |
|-----|-----|-----|
| 1   | 2   | 3   |
| 1   | 2   | 3   |
| 1   | 2   | 3   |
```

Resultado:

| foo | bar | baz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

## Alinhar texto das células na tabela

Ele suporta alinhamento de texto, usando:

- `---:` alinhar a direita
- `:---` alinhar a esquerda (por padrão TH e TD estão como left, então isso é dispensável)
- `:---:` alinhar no centro

Exemplo, código fonte:

```
direita | centro | esquerda | nativo
-------:|:------:|:---------|-------
1       | 2      | 3        | 4
1       | 2      | 3        | 4
1       | 2      | 3        | 4
```

Resultado:

| direita | centro | esquerda | nativo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

---

**Nota:** Aparentemente não há suporte para uma célula ocupar mais de um espaço, como no exemplo, creio que a sintaxe seria essa (se encontrar algo mais edito- ps: esse post é comunitário, testes são bem vindos):

```
foo | bar      ||
----|-----|-----|
1   | 2        ||
1   | 2   | 3   |
1   | 2   | 3   |
```

Resultado (para analisar no futuro se algo mudou):

| foo | bar |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Answer (score 5):

```
-- Teste de caracteres --

áéíóúâêîôûãõàèìòùäëïöüÿý
ÁÉÍÓÚÂÊÎÔÛÃÕÀÈÌÒÙÄËÏÖÜŸÝ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
0123456789

'"!@#$%¨&*()_+`{}^<>:?|
¹²³£¢¬Ồªº°/?°₢
\'
\"
'/
"/
_
__
___
____
_____
-
--
---
----
-----
/
//
///
////
/////
\
\\
\\\
\\\\
\\\\\
<b>teste</b>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Teste de HTML</a>
&#116;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#101;

"teste" 'teste' /teste/
\teste\ ~teste~ :teste:
[teste] %TESTE% (teste)
&teste& *teste* $teste$
^teste^ {teste} #teste#
@teste@ +teste+ ;teste;

❐ ❑ ❒ ❖ ❘ ❙ ❚ ❛ ❜ ❝ ❞ ❡ ❢ ❣ ❤
☀ ☁ ☂ ☃ ☄ ★ ☆ ☇ ☈ ☉ ☊ ☋ ☌ ☍ ☎
 ▁ ▂ ▃ ▄ ▅ ▆ ▇ █ ▉ ▊ ▋ ▌ ▍ ▎ ▏
 ⡋ ⡌ ⡍ ⡎ ⡏ ⡐ ⡑ ⡒ ⡓ ⡔ ⡕ ⡖ ⡗ ⡘ ⡙ ⡚ ⡛ ⡜ ⡝ ⡞
 ዓባይ ማደሪያ የለው፥ ግንድ ይዞ ይዞራል።


唯一のテストのためにメッセージ
消息僅用於測試目的
გაგზავნა მხოლოდ ტესტირების მიზნით
ข้อความเฉพาะสำหรับวัตถุประสงค์ในการทดสอบ
Сообщение только для тестовых целей
رسالة فقط لأغراض الاختبار
```

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Pause</kbd>

Comment: teste.... [ask] [answer] [tour]

Comment: (Teste)[google.com]

Answer (score 5):

Teste para montagem de tabela:

```
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────    
|   Nome        |   Email                   |   Sexo    |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|   Joaozinho   |   joao@joao.joao          |   H       |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|   Mariazinha  |   maria@maria.maria       |   M       |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
|   Carlinhos   |   carlos@carlos.carlos    |   H       |
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

---

com tags HTML:

NomeEmailSexoJoaozinhojoao@joao.joaoHMariazinhamaria@maria.mariaMCarlinhoscarlos@carlos.carlosM

Answer (score 5):

> Se estiver usando Opera primeiro instale (permite usar Chrome WebStore no Opera):
>
> - https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/download-chrome-extension-9/
>
> Então no Opera ou Chrome instale:
>
> - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tex-renderer/enfbnhdcmcipeoakalehejknkpbajodp

Teste inline: $ E = mc^2 $

Teste:

\begin{equation}
\left(!
\begin{array}{c}
n \
r
\end{array}
!\right) = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}
\end{equation}

Usando `<code>` (marcação) inline `$ E = mc^2 $`

Usando `<code><pre>` (marcação):

```
\begin{equation}
  \left(\!
    \begin{array}{c}
      n \\
      r
    \end{array}
  \!\right) = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}
\end{equation}
```

### Resultado esperado

> [image: latex]

Answer (score 5):

Testando para questionar uma pergunta no SOpt

[image: lê gato]

### Subtítulo

[image: lê gato]

### Outro subtítulo

[image: lê gato]

### Mais um subtítulo

[image: lê gato]

### Quarto e último

[image: lê gato]

Answer (score 5):

```
   _____  _  _          _                    
  / ____|| || |_       | |                   
 | |   |_  __  _|   ___| |__                 
 | |    _| || |_   / _ \ '_ \                
 | |___|_  __  _| |  __/ | | |               
  \_____||_||_|  _ \___|_| |_|               
                | | |                        
  _ __ ___   ___| | |__   ___  _ __          
 | '_ ` _ \ / _ \ | '_ \ / _ \| '__|         
 | | | | | |  __/ | | | | (_) | |            
 |_| |_| |_|\___|_|_| |_|\___/|_|            
                         | |                 
   __ _ _   _  ___       | | __ ___   ____ _ 
  / _` | | | |/ _ \  _   | |/ _` \ \ / / _` |
 | (_| | |_| |  __/ | |__| | (_| |\ V / (_| |
  \__, |\__,_|\___|  \____/ \__,_| \_/ \__,_|
     | |                                     
     |_|
```

Comment: Discordo! Java > C#!

Comment: @VictorStafusa Jamais. C# é lindo porque começa com C de Compaixão. Java começa com J de Desgraça.

Comment: A vantagem do C# é que é mais leve e funciona de diversas formas, a desvantagem é que ele sempre precisa da ajuda de outro framework, compilador ou algo do tipo para funcionar. Como o exemplo: você precisa construir um cavalo em C#, o cavalo funciona melhor se estiver disfarçado de camelo, se não estiver com o disfarce, ele fica teimoso

Answer (score 5):

Testando `<sup>`: 2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup>

Testando `<sub>`: 2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Misturado:
2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sup>2</sup><sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sub>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>222<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sup></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Isso `\`\`\\`\`` é renderizado como ``\`` e `\`\\`\`` é renderizado como `\``

Comment: Testando se HTML é renderizado nos comentários: `<test>fadfdsa</test> &lt;test&gt;` -> <test>fadfdsa</test> &lt;test&gt; `<br> <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>` -> <br> <a href="https://www.google.com">google</a>

Comment: Testando sup e sub: `a<sup>b</sup><sub>c</sub>`:  a<sup>b</sup><sub>c</sub>

Comment: testando `[meta-tag:debate]`: [meta-tag:debate]

Comment: Testando `[link com title](https://www.google.com "Texto que descreve o link")` - [link com title](https://www.google.com "Texto que descreve o link")

Answer (score 4):

*Teste URL:* https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

## A correção para o bug acima, seria:

*Teste URL:* https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 4):

## Colocar tags nas perguntas/respostas

Adicionando a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) à pergunta. Basta escrever "tag:php" envolvido com "[]"

## Colocar meta-tags nas perguntas/respostas

Digite `[meta-tag:<nome da tag>]`, por exemplo `[meta-tag:bug]` ficará assim [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Answer (score 3):

```js
var list = {};

$('button').on('click', function () {
 
 $('input').each(function (k, v) {
    var input = $(v);
    
    var key = input.data('room');
    var val = input.val();
    
    if(list[key])
      list[key].push(val);
    else    
      list[key] = [val];
  });
  
  console.log(list);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<input value="5" data-room="A1">
<input value="12" data-room="A2">
<input value="1" data-room="A3">
<input value="3" data-room="A4">
<input value="35" data-room="A4">

<button>GO!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

link to [a](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/sandbox-ou-chiqueirinho-de-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o/6492#answer-1824)

Comment: [help] > [edit] > [tour] > [ask] > [help/dont-ask] > [help/behavior]

Answer (score 3):

## Teste de formatação de código

### _____________________________

#### 1 Após cabeçalho com <kbd>{}</kbd>

```
.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
| :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
`------`------`------`------`------`------'
```

**2** Após Negrito com duplo `` e contendo `

`.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
| :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|`
------`------`------`------`------`------'`

*3* Após Itálico com <kbd>{}</kbd>

```
.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
| :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
`------`------`------`------`------`------'
```

- 4 Após Lista com marcadores ou Lista numerada com <kbd>{}</kbd>
- .....

  .------.------.------.------.------.------.
  |C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
  | :/: | :/: | :/: | (/) | :/: | :/: |
  | :/: | :/: | (__) | :/: | :/: | :/: |
  | '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
  `------`------`------`------`------`------'
- 5 Após Lista com marcadores ou Lista numerada com duplo `

  `.------.------.------.------.------.------.
  |C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
  | :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
  | :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
  | '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|`
  ------`------`------`------`------`------'`
- 6 Como <kbd>{}</kbd> dá um espaçamento de 4 "espaços", então utilizando 8 após listas...

  ```
  .------.------.------.------.------.------.
  |C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
  | :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
  | :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
  | '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
  `------`------`------`------`------`------'
  ```

---

7 Após linha horizontal com 8 espaços.

```
    .------.------.------.------.------.------.
    |C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
    | :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
    | :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
    | '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
    `------`------`------`------`------`------'
```

8 Citação

> .------.------.------.------.------.------. |C.--. |O.--. |D.--.
>   |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. | | :/: | :/: | :/: | (/) | :/: | :/: | |
>   :/: | :/: | (__) | :/: | :/: | :/: | | '--'C| '--'O| '--'D|
>   '--'I| '--'G| '--'O| `------`------`------`------`------`------'

9 Snippet

```html
    .------.------.------.------.------.------.
    |C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
    | :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
    | :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
    | '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
    `------`------`------`------`------`------'
```

10 Com  `code`

`.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/: | :/: | :/: | (/) | :/: | :/: |
| :/: | :/: | (__) | :/: | :/: | :/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
------------------------------------'`

- 11 Após Lista com marcadores ou Lista numerada com `<code>`

`.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/: | :/: | :/: | (/) | :/: | :/: |
| :/: | :/: | (__) | :/: | :/: | :/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
------------------------------------'`

12 Com `pre`  (`<desaparece>`, então usar `&lt;não desaparece>`)

```
.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
| :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
`------`------`------`------`------`------'
<test>
```

13 Com `pre code` (`<desaparece>`, então usar `&lt;não desaparece>`)

```
.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
| :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
`------`------`------`------`------`------'
<test>
```

14 Com duplo `code`

`.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/: | :/: | :/: | (/) | :/: | :/: |
| :/: | :/: | (__) | :/: | :/: | :/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
------------------------------`------'

Comment: `.------.------.------.------.------.------.
|C.--. |O.--. |D.--. |I.--. |G.--. |O.--. |
| :/\: | :/\: | :/\: | (\/) | :/\: | :/\: |
| :\/: | :\/: | (__) | :\/: | :\/: | :\/: |
| '--'C| '--'O| '--'D| '--'I| '--'G| '--'O|
`------`------`------`------`------`------'`

Answer (score 3):

Formatação de tabelas usando https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

## Output styles

#### ASCII (mysql style)

```
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
|               Col1               |  Col2   |          Col3          | Numeric Column |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
| Value 1                          | Value 2 | 123                    |           10.0 |
| Separate                         | cols    | with a tab or 4 spaces |       -2,027.1 |
| This is a row with only one cell |         |                        |                |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
```

#### ASCII (separated)

```
+==================================+=========+========================+================+
|               Col1               |  Col2   |          Col3          | Numeric Column |
+==================================+=========+========================+================+
| Value 1                          | Value 2 | 123                    |           10.0 |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
| Separate                         | cols    | with a tab or 4 spaces |       -2,027.1 |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
| This is a row with only one cell |         |                        |                |
+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------+----------------+
```

#### ASCII (dots):

```
........................................................................................
:               Col1               :  Col2   :          Col3          : Numeric Column :
:..................................:.........:........................:................:
: Value 1                          : Value 2 : 123                    :           10.0 :
: Separate                         : cols    : with a tab or 4 spaces :       -2,027.1 :
: This is a row with only one cell :         :                        :                :
:..................................:.........:........................:................:
```

#### Unicode

```
╔══════════════════════════════════╦═════════╦════════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║               Col1               ║  Col2   ║          Col3          ║ Numeric Column ║
╠══════════════════════════════════╬═════════╬════════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Value 1                          ║ Value 2 ║ 123                    ║           10.0 ║
║ Separate                         ║ cols    ║ with a tab or 4 spaces ║       -2,027.1 ║
║ This is a row with only one cell ║         ║                        ║                ║
╚══════════════════════════════════╩═════════╩════════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

#### Unicode (single line)

```
┌──────────────────────────────────┬─────────┬────────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│               Col1               │  Col2   │          Col3          │ Numeric Column │
├──────────────────────────────────┼─────────┼────────────────────────┼────────────────┤
│ Value 1                          │ Value 2 │ 123                    │           10.0 │
│ Separate                         │ cols    │ with a tab or 4 spaces │       -2,027.1 │
│ This is a row with only one cell │         │                        │                │
└──────────────────────────────────┴─────────┴────────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

Esse é um teste de magic link [ask]

Comment: Não correu bem [ask] ;)

Comment: Queria ver se funcionava também nos posts :P

Comment: [chat] ........

Comment: te**s**te [....]

Comment: [about] .......

Comment: _**_**_._**_**_

Answer (score 2):

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > Volta pra esquerda, mano.

<kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd><kbd>se inscreve no canal e dá like</kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd></kbd>

teste

````
                ;'-. 
    `;-._        )  '---.._
      >  `-.__.-'          `'.__
     /_.-'-._         _,   ^ ---)
     `       `'------/_.'----```
                     `
````

---

---

---

---

---

---

---

Answer (score 2):

Eu sou novo na página e não sei como relatar isso aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tomando negativo no sand box? Vocês são os caras. Parabéns!

Comment: é porque a postagem não carregou :P

Comment: @CypherPotato Aqui carregou normalmente. Que navegador está utilizando?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss aqui está carregando infinitamente... estou no Internet Explorer 6 no meu Windows XP

Comment: @CypherPotato funciona melhor com o Nestscape Navigator.

Comment: @AugustoVasques tava baixando o Comodo Dragon aqui

Comment: puts agora que vi que o Comodo ainda existe

Comment: Três negativos :D

Comment: Três pessoas esperando o print carregar.

Answer (score 2):

<--! -->

Pelo visto não podemos esconder nenhum texto dentro da formatação, ou podemos?
(edite a pergunta para descobrir)

Comment: Na verdade vc pode fazer assim `>! esse texto é oculto` dessa forma vc esconde o texto, mas fica uma "marcação" na caixa de texto, e caso o usuário faça o :hover nessa marcação o "texto oculto" vai aparece. Faça um teste escrevendo ">! texto oculto" no campo de resposta para vc ver como funciona

Comment: Sim, eu conheço o `>!` . Meu objetivo era tentar esconder um texto de uma forma que não pudesse ser visto normalmente por um usuário, ah não ser que ele edite a respsota

Comment: Hi there, Riki, I need your help, in trying to help with your Meta.SE question.  I hope you see this comment.  See https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8057/170215

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um teste, para uma sugestão para o colega [@Articuno](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/171579) durante o WinterBash

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
```

Answer (score 1):

Ui!

<sup>Nota de rodapé</sup>

Answer (score 1):

| Importante |
| --- |
| Essa resposta está escondida por ter sido considerada extremamente e inexplicavelmente ofensiva pelo autor. Clique [aqui](/#) para saber mais. |

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

## Task<Dictionary>

### Task<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>

<<>>
<<<a>>>

List

```
List<string>
```