# Como este comentário conseguiu fazer Multiline?

Tags: suporte, comentários, formatação

Nunca tinha visto [algo semelhante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32842/click-linha-de-uma-datatable-jquery-e-carregar-uma-p%c3%a1gina-com-informa%c3%a7%c3%b5es-do-id#comment62687_32881):

<kbd>[image: snapshot do comentário]</kbd>

Inspecionando o HTML mostra:

<kbd>[image: html do comentário]</kbd>

Será que algum moderador pode ver qual foi o markdown que gerou isso?

Comment: [Conforme o @bfav abaixo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2011/como-este-coment%C3%A1rio-conseguiu-fazer-multiline#comment6220_2012):

Comment: `you're_           doing_           it_wrong()           :P           `

Comment: Parece que andaram mudando algo na forma de exibição dos comentários e não é mais possível fazer o multiline D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade, [fiz uma simulação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/sandbox-ou-chiqueirinho-de-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o/1788#comment6219_1788) e vários espaços em branco dentro de um code block de comentários (dentro de ``` `` ``` ) produzem o efeito.

Markdown do comentário:

```
Aqui funciona, mas no CLICK utilizo `$('td.readonly').on('click', function (e) {` Adiciono Classes as colunas usando o `"aoColumns" : [                                             {                                                       "sClass" : "readonly",                                                      "sTitle": "ID",                                                     "aTargets": [0]                                                 } ]`. Tentou debugar? Aparece algum erro?
```

Comment: `parece            que            vários            tabs            em             código            inline            criam            esse            efeito`

Comment: `testando  com  duas  tabulações  entre  as  palavras`

Comment: *Meu chiqueirinho de tabulação* :D @bfavaretto O primeiro exemplo tá troll total!

Comment: Acabei de descobrir que não funciona no site mobile