# Falha na formatação de código {} em uma resposta

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Ao responder uma pergunta, notei que a formatação de código [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] não funciona corretamente quando inserida imediatamente após uma lista[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].

Notem na imagem abaixo que inseri um ponto entre a lista e o código para que a formatação funcionasse corretamente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Exemplo do Bug:**

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

   SELECT * FROM Tabela

No caso o `SELECT * FROM Tabela` acima está entre chaves **{}**

Comment: Veja [este teste](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6711/75104) no Sandbox ou faça uns testes por lá ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caso queira inserir o código após a lista sem tem que indentar, eu costumo colocar um `<!-- -->` antes do código. Ele ficará invisível na publicação, mas servirá para remover a dependência com a lista:

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
```

Comment: bom macete, obrigado.

Comment: Não me tinha lembrado ainda desse truque! Boa

Answer (score 9):

Na verdade é assim mesmo. Quando tem um código depois de um item de lista precisa dar 8 espaços e não apenas 4, já que 4 são para ajustar parágrafo dentro da lista e 4 é que fazem a identificação que é um código que precisa de marcação especial.

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

   ```
   SELECT * FROM Tabela
   ```

Comment: Opa, não sabia disso, obrigado o/