# Bloco de quote com comportamento anômalo quando em modo de "spoiler"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, perguntas, respostas, design

Estava verificando de maneira curiosa o chiqueirinho de formatação e me encontro com o "bloco de spoiler". Esse bloco é praticamente idêntico ao de citação, porém escondendo o conteúdo.

Post que eu vi: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1788/64969

Reproduzo abaixo:

> conseguem ver esse spoiler?

Quando ele está "em modo spoiler", o fundo antigo do bloco de citação continua o mesmo (pelo menos aqui no meta). Quando está com o mouse por cima, ele faz a transição para exibir o conteúdo, mas o fundo continua o mesmo. Se você clicar, o bloco sai do "modo spoiler" e se torna uma citação normal, com o fundo do atual "bloco de citação":

[image: bloco de spoiler perdendo o fundo]

No meu ver, é um comportamento não desejável essa mudança de fundo.

Ah, sim, ao clicar de novo no bloco de spoiler, ele volta a ficar em "modo spoiler" e volta a ter o fundo do antigo bloco de citação.

Estou usando Firefox 73.0.1 no Windows 10. Verifiquei o mesmo comportamento no Chrome 80.0.3987.132 (Versão oficial) 64 bits (cohort: Stable). Mesma coisa no Microsoft Edge, porém não consegui ver a versão dele.

Comment: Comigo não aconteceu. Mas muita gente acha que o problema é a mudança toda que ficou ruim. E não foi isso, quem anda mexendo nos CSS além de introduzir bugs está deixando feio.

Comment: @Maniero, qual o browser? Acabei de reproduzir no Chrome aqui. Por mais feio que as coisas fiquem, se ficar pelo menos um feio consistente tem menos WTF para o usuário, então a qualidade do software fica maior. Onde foi que li que a qualidade do software é definida pela quantidade de WTF que o usuário dá ao usar o sistema?

Comment: Eu gostei desse feedback visual pra mostrar que não está mais no mesmo modo

Comment: No novo Edge, que deveria ser a mesma coisa.

Comment: Tá ficando bem feio mesmo, principalmente no perfil, aquele laranja é horrível

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/afaRHfz

Comment: Persiste este problema, @JeffersonQuesado?

Comment: @JNat, sim, persiste aqui no meta (vou ver no site principal), pelo menos no Firefox. Não notei diferença alguma do gif que eu registrei para o momento atual, então fazer outra gravação dessas me parece redundante, mas posso fazer para evidenciar meu ponto

Comment: Acrescentei a tag [tag:status-revisão], de acordo com [o novo processo que estamos a experimentar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345032/208518). Acrescento ainda que para bugs como estes, adicionar a tag [tag:design] também faz com que a equipa de design veja o post mais rapidamente :)

Comment: @JNat No site principal, o bloco de spoiler tá com a mesma cor cinza que tem aqui no meta. Testei na visualização ao vivo como em uma postagem minha que tinha um bloco de spoiler

Comment: @JNat, obrigado pela dica da tag. Havia me enganado e colocado [meta-tag:layout] no lugar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema parece ter ficado resolvido com correcções recentes ao [componente `.s-prose` no Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/prose/#content).