# O botão "Copiar para uma nova resposta" não funciona quando há paginação nas respostas?

Tags: bug, respostas

Percebi esse problema no SOen e resolvi fazer uns testes pelo SOpt. Não encontrei uma pergunta que tenha muitas respostas (máximo que achei foi 21 resposta) a ponto de ter sofrido paginação. Fique a vontade para sugerir uma pergunta nos comentário caso encontre :).

Fiz uma análise no META e encontrei esta pergunta: *[Sandbox (ou "chiqueirinho") de formatação](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317/sandbox-ou-chiqueirinho-de-formata%C3%A7%C3%A3o?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)*, e para testar e fui diretamente para [esta resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6150/95771). Cliquei no botão <kbd>Copiar para uma nova resposta</kbd> e confirmei que botão não funciona nesses casos em que há paginação nas respostas, não aperece o snippet, etc..., porém nenhuma mensagem é informada. Este caso se repetiu no META, exatamente como no SOen, logo eu acredito que o problema deva acontecer da mesma forma no SOpt.

Talvez esse comportamento pode estar relacionado ao aviso que é informado quando uma pergunta já possui várias respostas (não sei o número ao certo). Quando há uma tentativa de se postar uma nova resposta em uma pergunta que já possui diversas respostas, é mostrado um aviso e talvez essa lógica de mostrar o aviso possa causar o não funcionamento do botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Este problema (se é que posso chamar) foi mapeado?
- Esse *não funcionamento* está relacionado com o aviso mostrado na imagem acima?
- Já foi discutido algo sobre no META? (Não encontrei nenhum post a respeito...)
- Talvez poderíamos exibir o mesmo aviso (demonstrado acima) quando o botão for clicado para uma pergunta com a mesmo situação, não?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talvez este comportamento seja [status-intencional](/questions/tagged/status-intencional)? Mas vamos por partes.

---

## Aviso de "*mais de 30 respostas*" (sem *snippet*)

No [link que você usou para testar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6150/95771), se você ir para o final da página, verá que tem o botão "*Responder a esta pergunta*":

[image: Botão "Responder a esta pergunta", para perguntas com mais de 30 respostas]

[Segundo o Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84870/401803), este botão é mostrado quando a pergunta possui mais de X respostas (sendo que para a maioria dos sites, incluindo o SOpt, o valor de X é **30**). Ao clicar neste botão, é mostrado o aviso "*Esta pergunta já tem mais de 30 respostas...*", e só depois de clicar OK no aviso, é que o editor é mostrado, para que se possa escrever a resposta.

Compare, por exemplo, com esta pergunta (ou com qualquer outra com menos de 30 respostas), que mostra o editor em vez do botão:

[image: Editor, para perguntas com menos de 30 respostas]

Ou seja, para perguntas com mais de 30 respostas, você tem que clicar no botão "*Responder a esta pergunta*", clicar OK no aviso "*Esta pergunta já tem mais de 30 respostas...*", e só aí abre-se o editor para que você digite a resposta:

[image: Editor se abre depois de clicar no botão e no aviso]

---

## E o *snippet*?

Bom, na [resposta que você indicou](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6150/95771), ao clicar em "*Copiar para uma nova resposta*", a página é rolada até o final, e realmente não aparece nenhum aviso. Mas se você clicar no botão "*Responder a esta pergunta*" e depois dar OK no aviso "*Esta pergunta já tem mais de 30 respostas...*", verá que o editor será aberto com o *snippet* corretamente copiado:

[image: snippet copiado corretamente]

Talvez não seja muito intuitivo que precise clicar no botão "*Responder a esta pergunta*", mas aí acho que é outro *bug* (ou talvez [novo-recurso](/questions/tagged/novo-recurso)?), já que o *bug* reportado aqui é que o *snippet* não é copiado (ele é, talvez o que precise melhorar é a interface, de forma a deixar mais claro que precisa clicar naquele botão para que seja possível prosseguir com a resposta).

Comment: Então não é bug, é uma __feature-charada__, você tem que descobrir que o botão funciona kkkkkk